# What do column flags mean in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench

In MySQL Workbench table editor there are 7 column flags available: PK, NN, UQ, BIN, UN, ZF, AI.

PK obviously stands for Primary Key. What about others?

Comment: There is a tooltip feature request at [bugs.mysql.com](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47488).

Comment: MySQL Workbench 6.3 already features the tooltip, I haven't noticed!

Answer (score 365, accepted):

PK  - Primary Key

NN  - Not Null

BIN - Binary (stores data as binary strings.  There is no character set so sorting and comparison is based on the numeric values of the bytes in the values.)

UN  - Unsigned (non-negative numbers only.  so if the range is -500 to 500, instead its 0 - 1000, the range is the same but it starts at 0)

UQ  - Create/remove Unique Key

ZF  - Zero-Filled (if the length is 5 like INT(5) then every field is filled with 0’s to the 5th digit.   12 = 00012, 400 = 00400, etc. )

AI  - Auto Increment

G - Generated column. i.e. value generated by a formula based on the other columns

Comment: @Ivan: A unique constraint ensures that a value can only ever exist in the column *once*.  Any attempt to add a duplicate will result in an unique data constraint error.  The unique constraint as supports covering more than one column - this is called a composite.

Comment: @Ivan -- it is a way to help index values while preventing duplicates. For example -- e-mail and SSN fields for a unique list of customers should be a unique index, since you frequently do lookups using those fields and they shouldn't repeat. For arbitrary values used only by your database internally for frequent lookups (such as customer ID), you should use a primary key with an auto-increment option instead.

Comment: UQ works by adding a unique index so as to maintain the uniqeness check. You do not need to set it if the columns is already the sole member of the primary key as the primary key is assumed to be unique.

Comment: Some tooltips would be really nice here.

Comment: @VasiliyDeych, So for `UQ`, `U` means unique. What does `Q` mean?

Comment: @Pacerier it's not an acronym or initialism, it's just an abbreviation. `UQ` means unique.

Comment: @wmassingham, `UK` should be the right choice  since we have `PK`, `ZF`, and `AI`.

Comment: @vasiliyDeych: what is the use of `BIN` flag when I've set a conflicting datatype (eg. `VARCHAR(10)`) or a corresponding binary string datatype (eg. `BINARY(10)`) ? When should I exactly use this flag? Is it permissible to use in case of columns with `BINARY` datatype only?

Comment: What about "G"?

Comment: If you have more than one unique column, it's better to set that up on the indexes tab, so you have more control about grouping them.

Comment: G = Generated column. i.e. value generated by a formula based on the other columns.

Answer (score 19):

Here is the source of these column flags

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-columns-tab.html

Comment: It looks like MySQL team moved the page to this url: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-columns-tab.html

Comment: It would help if some of the information from the page was in the answer, rather than just having a link. That way the answer is safe even if the link goes down (again).

Answer (score 0):

This exact question is answered on [mySql workbench-faq](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/workbench-faq.html#faq-workbench-column-acronyms):

> Hover over an acronym to view a description, and see the Section 8.1.11.2, “The Columns Tab” and MySQL CREATE TABLE documentation for additional details.

That means hover over an acronym in the mySql Workbench table editor.

[Section 8.1.11.2, “The Columns Tab”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-columns-tab.html)