# MySQL flags for an image

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have got a column of images in my MySQL database, but I would like to know what column flag I should use? (PK, NN, UQ, BIN, UN, ZF, AI) Or do they even matter?

Edit: maybe I should mention that it's a blob datatype

Thanks..

Comment: Hava a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663952/what-do-column-flags-mean-in-mysql-workbench

Comment: Huh?  I have no idea what those flags mean (Primary Key? Not Nullable? etc.?).  Also, Why do you think you should be storing images as blobs in a DB? 999 times out of 1000, when you see this sort of design, it is a bad idea.

Comment: I have seen that page, but I dont think that page will help me? Sorry for my ignorance ;)

Comment: [storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/)

Comment: Okey, storing as a blob was what I've been told to do, could you give me an alternative?

Comment: @FilipRosén Store a file path reference only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Understand what each flag means:

- `PK`: **Primary key**: Meant for primary keys (obviously, a BLOB can't be a PK)
- `NN`: **Not nullable**: Is the field mandatory? If it is, use this flag
- `UQ`: **Unique**: Forces a unique index on the column (again, not a good idea on a BLOB)
- `BIN`: **Binary**: Stores strings as binary strings (not necesary for BLOB)
- `UN`: **Unsigned**: Only non-negative numbers (could a BLOB be positive or negative?)
- `ZF`: **Zero-fill**: Left-pad number values with zeros (do I really need to say anything related to BLOBs regarding this?)
- `AI`: **Auto-incremental** (Do I really need to explain this?)