# When to use the BIN flag in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I came to know that MySQL Workbench allows a `BIN` flag on a column for **storing data as binary strings** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663952/what-do-column-flags-mean-in-mysql-workbench#3663971).

If that's the case, what's the difference between `BIN` flag and the datatype `BINARY(n)`? Besides, it even allows me to set this flag on columns with datatypes `VARCHAR(n)`, `CHAR(n)`, etc. which seems to be conflicting.

When should I exactly use this flag?

Comment: Is your question when to use `binary` or what? If it's about using MySQL workbench then it's offtopic since it's not about a programming problem.

Comment: No. It's not about when to use `binary`. I need to know the difference between the *flag* and the *datatype*. Why need flag when we have a datatype?

Comment: I see, well the bin flat and character data types seem to be mutually exclusive. The flag is probably to tell you extras about the column (unique, primary key etc). However, why and how those flags work exactly - that's something what Workbench dev will have to answer. Also, since your question is about a tool and not programming problem, we're slightly offtopic here.

Comment: You got a Workbench dev in your contacts list? :P I would beg to differ. The designing part plays a role in the future programming. Besides, why would SO allow a `mysql-workbench` tag in my question with over 2.2k questions?

Comment: Your question is about a tool and what something means in that tool. I don't see how that can be a programming problem. Also, it's not that hard to email people who maintain MySQL Workbench. What I'm saying is that you haven't presented a programming problem - that means you are not likely to get an answer to your question. You obviously found a logical bug in the program - why are mutually exclusive data type and "flag" able to "work" together. I agree it's intriguing question, but it's definitely better to ask on [this forum](http://forums.mysql.com/list.php?152).

Comment: I'll drink to that. Still I think it's worth putting up the question here. People might get into a similar confusion in future. Hopefully, we'll have an answer for them here on SO. :)

Comment: I won't vote to close, I do agree with you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the manual entry [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html). The most obvious use for this is where you have an ID rather than text where you may want an ID of, say, "A107652B" to be distinct from "a107652b". Most textual types would treat these as the same.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I understand the meaning of `BINARY` datatype. I want to know: How does the `BIN` *flag* differ from `BINARY` *datatype* ? If the flag serves any purpose for some reason, shouldn't be it allowed only on columns with `BINARY` datatype?

Comment: Ah, my apologies - in terms of storage and how mysql treats the data under the hood, no, there is no difference. Using the Bin flag on a char/varchar column is a convenience for humans however as it allows us to enter data into, and view data in, that column using strings rather than having to use numbers.